# errores de javascript en PageSpeed Insights

Tags: javascript, seo, googlepagespeed

estoy intentando mejorar mi seo con page speed insights

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')

at banner_publicidad_productos

 at content_menu_filtro

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at ajax.onreadystatechange
```

ahora lo que no entiendo es que estoy ejecutando mi código y no tengo errores en consola,  los substring que tengo los verifique esta dando el resultado bien, el Json.parsen también se ejecuta sin problema, entonces es normal que pueda darme errores asi?

por aca le dejo la edicion con el codigo amigo,  seria el php en el que llamo al json mediante la función  tasa_bin_pag_web

asi llamo al json desde php

```
    $Result_tasas_binance = tasa_bin_pag_web();

            header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
            echo json_encode($Result_tasas_binance);




function tasa_bin_pag_web(){

$consult = "SELECT  idtasa_biance, idpais, tasa_binance FROM $Tasa_pais_binc";
$resultado=mysqli_prepare($conexion, $consult);
$ok=mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);
if($ok==true){
$ok=mysqli_stmt_bind_result($resultado, $idtasa_biance, $idpais, $tasa_binance);

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($resultado)){


        $Result_tasas_binance[] = [
            $array_idtasa_biance => $idtasa_biance,
            $array_idpais_binance => $idpais,
            $array_tasa_binance => $tasa_binance
    ];

}

return $Result_tasas_binance;
mysqli_stmt_close($resultado);
}


}



consult_tasa_bin();


function consult_tasa_bin() {

   
 let ajax = xmlhttp();

    var url = '../../reme/agg_empag/ssdae.php';

   
ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
   
 if(ajax.readyState==4){

   tasas_binan = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);

       }
   } 

   ajax.open("GET",url,true);
   ajax.send(null);
   return false;

 }
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Añade contexto al error. Comparte el código, de la línea del error o el fragmento del `JSON.parse()`

Comment: listo amigo ya le coloque el código php  con el que llamo al json a ver si tiene algún error, gracias de antemano

Comment: casualmente voy a abrir una pregunta similar a tu error, lograste resolver? también tengo errores en  el pagespeed  pero en mi consola todo esta perfecto y el error me lo da solo en movil, si veo el seo de la web no arroja errores  :/